# Python 3.2: cx_freeze compiles my program, but in debug mode

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, pygame, cx-freeze

I'm making a game with Python 3.2 and Pygame.  I've successfully managed to use `cx_freeze` to bundle everything into an executable, and it runs.  Fine.  The only problem is, **even when I pass the `-OO` flag to my `setup.py`, my game is compiled in debug mode.**  (I've confirmed it with `print` statements that `__debug__` is indeed `True`.)

The problem is, my game has debugging features that are disabled automatically in release mode.  I don't want to distribute the debugging features of my game, and I don't want to have to remove them from the code manually.

My `setup.py`, shortened here for brevity, is as follows:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includes     = [<some modules>]
excludes     = [<some unwanted modules>]
include_files = [<game assets>]


build_options = {
                 'append_script_to_exe':True,
                 'bin_excludes':excludes,
                 'compressed':True,
                 'excludes': excludes,
                 'include_files': include_files,
                 'includes': includes,
                 'optimize':2,
                 'packages': ['core', 'game'],
                 }

common_exe_options = {
                      'appendScriptToExe'  : True,
                      'appendScriptToLibrary':True,
                      'compress'           : True,
                      'copyDependentFiles' : True,
                      'excludes'           : excludes,
                      'includes'           : includes, 
                      'script'             : '__init__.py',
                     }

executable = Executable(**common_exe_options)

setup(name='Invasodado',
      version='0.8',
      description='wowza!',
      options = {'build_exe': build_options,
                 'bdist_msi': build_options},
      executables=[executable])
```

The full script, as with the rest of my code, can be found at https://github.com/CorundumGames/Invasodado/blob/master/setup.py .

On Ubuntu 12.10, I'm building with `python3.2 -OO setup.py build`.  On Windows XP, I'm building with `C:\Python32\python -OO setup.py build`.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: This is a massive problem for opengl code: things like pyglet and pyopengl, if I remember correctly, will perform a bunch of expensive safety checks at runtime if not run optimised, slowing the code down an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two slightly separate things: the optimisation for compiling your code to bytecode, and the optimisation the interpreter runs with. Setting `optimize` in the options for cx_Freeze optimises the bytecode it produces, but the interpreter still runs with `__debug__ == True`.

It seems there's no easy way to set the debug flag for the embedded interpreter. It ignores the `PYTHONOPTIMIZE` environment variable. As a workaround, you could do use a debug flag like:

```
debug = __debug__ and not hasattr(sys, 'frozen')
```

Comment: How do you know there's no easy way to do it?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I've tried the obvious things (run with -O, set PYTHONOPTIMIZE environment variable), and they don't work. And there's nothing I've seen in the docs or the source code to point to a way.

Comment: That's a shame: Sometimes the debug assertions are in 3rd party code (e.g. pyopengl) which perform very expensive safety checks unless run with \_\_debug\_\_ == False.

Comment: A dumb question: where am I supposed to put this debug flag? Inside setup.py, on the command line "python setup.exe --debug", or somewhere else? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The example I gave would go in your application code, and then you'd use `if debug:` to check it (before doing e.g. extra logging). It's a workaround, because I couldn't see a way to actually disable Python's own debug mode. That was in 2013, though - things might have changed since then.